# Include another project via ant in android

Tags: android, ant, properties, jar

I'm trying to include a no-android project into my android-project via ant. It's a common-project, which can change every time, so I can't create a .jar file and export it to the "libs" folder.

Can anyone help me?

Do I have to change somthing in my project.properties?

Thank you very much!

Comment: this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8457727/adding-non-android-project-to-an-android-project) might help.

Comment: hey, thank you for the reply. I forgot to mention that I'm using Continous Integration (Jenkins) and I think I can't link a folder in jenkins :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [apache ivy plugin](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) to declare a dependency between the projects. The [Jenkins ivy plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Ivy+Plugin) can then be used to detect changes and automatically trigger a build of your project after a build of the common project.

Comment: hey, thank you! I'll give it a try ;) But there will be still a problem: I can't integrate another project into my android-project. I've tried everything... How can i tell the ant-file that it should integrate the common-project ? Thank you

Comment: @user1484047 If you use ivy, you can declare a dependency against the latest version of the jar produced by the common-project. So, every time a new version of the common project is built, the ivy Jenkins plugin will rebuild your project (that depends upon it)

Answer (score 0):

```
<target name="-pre-compile">
<path id="project.all.jars.path">
    <path path="${toString:project.all.jars.path}"/>
    <fileset dir="${jar.libs.dir}">
        <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>
```

If i integrate this into my build.xml my project will include the library correctly ;)